# Detect cloth sizes with regex

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to detect with regex, strings that have a pattern of {any_number}{x-}{large|medium|small} for a site with clothing I am building in PHP.
I have managed to match the sizes against a preconfigured set of strings by using:

```
$searchFor = '7x-large';
$regex = '/\b'.$searchFor.'\b/';

//Basically, it's finding the letters 
//surrounded by a word-boundary (the \b bits). 
//So, to find the position:
preg_match($regex, $opt_name, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

I even managed to detect weird sizes like 41 1/2 with regex, but I am not an expert and I am having a hard time on this.

I have come up with

```
preg_match("/^(?<![\/\d])([xX\-])(large|medium|small)$/", '7x-large', $match);
```

but it won't work.

Could you pinpoint what I am doing wrong?

Comment: why you used a look behind?

Comment: Sorry it was frustrated code. When start doing anything to make it work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you also want to match half sizes. You can use something like this:

```
$theregex = '~(?i)^\d+(?:\.5)?x-(?:large|medium|small)$~';
if (preg_match($theregex, $yourstring,$m)) {
    // Yes! It matches!
    // the match is $m[0]
    } 
else { // nah, no luck...
     }
```

Note that the `(?i)` makes it case-insensitive.

This also assumes you are validating that an entire string conforms to the pattern. If you want to find the pattern as a substring of a larger string, remove the `^` and `$` anchors:

```
$theregex = '~(?i)\d+(?:\.5)?x-(?:large|medium|small)~';
```

Comment: Very interesting. I am not so good with regex so I use examples and try things to see what works for me or not. I have not see the use of tildes (~) before in a regex string. Is it used as replacement for slashes (/)? I mean '/(?i)\d+(?:\.5)?x-(?:large|medium|small)/' will work the same, right? If not what's their difference?

Comment: Yes, you can use any delimiter you like in a regex string for php. Slashes are a nuisance because you need them to escape them all the time (in `http://`)... Among alternate delimiters, some of the more convenient are `~`, `%`, `@`... but of course you have to escape them if they happen in the string. :)

Comment: Yes indeed. I looked it up and it turns out you can use all those characters and even "#". It comes with the PCRE I guess and it helps keep your regex clean from stuff like {/\d+}.

Comment: Yep. From experience, `~` is one of the best. You rarely have to escape it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the specification you have and build it up piece by piece. You want "{any_number}{x-}{large|medium|small}".

"{any_number}" would be `\d+`. This does not allow fractional numbers such as `12.34`, but the question does not specify whether they are required.

"{x-}" is a simple string `x-`

"{large|medium|small}" is a choice between three alternatives `large|medium|small`.

Joining the pieces together gives `\d+x-(large|medium|small)`. Note the brackets around the alternation, without then the expression would be interpreted as `(\d+x-large)|medium|small`.

You mention "*weird sizes like 41 1/2*" but without specifying how "*weird*" the number to be matched are. You need a precise specification of what you include in "*weird*" before you can extend the regular expression.

Comment: So my code will be something like this 
preg_match("/^\d+x-(large|medium|small)$/", '7-xlarge', $match); or this
preg_match("/^([\d+])([x])\-(large|medium|small)$/", '7-xlarge', $match); I have tested both but the doesn't work

Comment: For the weitd size reference I used  preg_match_all("/(?<![\/\d])(?:\d+)\s*(?<![\/\d])(?:\d+)\/(?:\d+)(?![\/\d])/",'41 1/2',$matches, PREG_SET_ORDER); To match any numbers that have the pattern of {number}{spaces}{number}{/}{number}

Comment: @GeorgeB  post some examples of what you're trying to match and what won't?

Comment: Oh I am sorry I had a typo in my search string. That's why it won't return anything. I fixed it  but now it returns '7x-large' & 'large'. I need only to look and match for '7x-large' or '5X-Large' or even '3XX-large' if that's possible ( ignore multiple occurences of 'x')